# In Access, is the "falsepart" of the IIf Function required?

Tags: ms-access, required

While converting some Access queries to T-SQL, I came across the Access function IIf.  I read the documentation [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) and understand it takes 3 parameters:  the expression, the if true, and the if false.  What I have yet to find is if the "false" param is required?  And if a false is not provided, what is the behavior?

**UPDATE:**
When this question was asked, I did not ***know*** if the query worked with only 2 parameters (b/c I can not run the query in Access).  I did, however, ***suspect it might work*** (with only 2 params) b/c a few queries I am converting (to T-SQL) have nested IIF's and the last IIF has only 2 params.

Comment: It's `IIf`, and the doc you linked states clearly that all 3 parameters are required.

Comment: Andre, yes you are correct, (and I was aware) the doc clearly states all 3 are required.  My confusion came b/c the queries I was assigned to convert -- several of them have nested IIF's in which the final IFF has only two parameters.  Normally I would run the query and see what happens, but for several reasons, I can not run the queries.  So I suppose my primary motive was to determine what was the intent of the person who wrote the query in the first place, and to determine what should happen (in Access) if IIF is given only 2 params.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't know that. It would be very useful if you'd add this info (that the function actually works in queries with only 2 parameters) to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `IIf`, not `IFF`. All arguments are required in VBA and textbox expressions and both must be calculatable (no error result such as DivBy0) because both parts will be calculated - if either errors, the entire expression errors. The IIf() in Access query works differently - 'falsepart' calculates only if 'truepart' fails and if 'falsepart' is not provided, expression returns Null if 'truepart' fails.

Try some expressions and see what happens. One for testing: `IIf(1=2,"T")`.

Comment: June7, 1) the part of your answer "IIf() in query works differently" is what I was looking for.  2) I tried the IIF in T-SQL, and "SELECT IIf(1=2,'T')" errors "Incorrect syntax" if not given a 3rd argument, but 3) I tried it in Access and running the query "SELECT IIf(1=2,"T")" shows an empty cell.  May i assume the "empty cell" is what you mean by "returns Null if 'truepart' fails"?

Comment: Yes, result is Null as opposed to an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

Addendum to June7's excellent answer:

Here are two simple queries that work in Access SQL:

```
SELECT IIf(1=1, "yes")
```

(returns "yes")

```
SELECT IsNull(IIf(1=2, "yes"))
```

(returns -1 aka True) - so if you omit `falsepart`, `IIf()` returns indeed NULL if `expr` doesn't evaluate to True.

Comment: Andre, great Addendum, and very much clears up the ambiguity.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's required, it's actually like an if else statement.

i.e an action occurs if the condition is fulfilled, and another action occurs if condition is not fulfilled